# URL mapping of /test to /home/index.jsf only results in 404

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-rewriting, prettyfaces

I've been trying to set up OCPsoft's Rewrite http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/examples/ for JSF 2.2.

My setup:

- JSF 2.2
- Tomcat 7
- Servlet Container 3.0
- Maven Project
- URLRewrite Version 2.0.12

My pom.xml includes the following two dependencies

```
<!-- for JSF 2.x -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ocpsoft.rewrite</groupId>
        <artifactId>rewrite-config-prettyfaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have placed a pretty-config.xml in my WEB-INF folder

```
    <pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                      http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

    <url-mapping id="test">
        <pattern value="/test" />
        <view-id value="/home/index.jsf" />
    </url-mapping>

</pretty-config>
```

My web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>myproject</display-name>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
        <param-value>primefaces:jquery/jquery.js=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: "client" or "server" (= default) 
        See JSF Specification 2.5.2. Zur Produktion wieder auf server schalten. HTTP 
        GET Request zusammen mit 'client'
    führen zum Verlust des STATE</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Next step - disable compression of state in server</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.COMPRESS_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that 
            it is "human readable". i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will 
            be written, that do not influence
        the HTML code. Default: "true"</description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Very important, too, is to disable the serialization 
        of state, serialization and deserialization of the component tree is a
        major
        performance hit
    </description>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Verschlüsselung des Viewstates -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.secret</param-name>
        <param-value>NzY1NDMyMTA=</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
        <param-value>3</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/404.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/home/index.jsf</location>
    </error-page>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>adminPinFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.filters.AdminPinFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>facesRedirectFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.filters.FacesRedirectFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <description>Auf diese Extension soll nicht direkt zugegriffen
                    werden
                    (z.B. .xhtml)</description>
            <param-name>forbiddenExtension</param-name>
            <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <description>Auf diese Extension soll umgeleitet werden (z.B. .jsf)</description>
            <param-name>redirectExtension</param-name>
            <param-value>.jsf</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>directGetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.filters.DirectGetFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.filters.SessionFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.filters.AuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>offerFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.filters.OfferFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>adminAuthFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.myproject.filters.AdminAuthFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>adminPinFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/adminPin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>facesRedirectFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/profile/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/conversation/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>adminAuthFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/panel/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>offerFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/offer/view/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <!-- Disables URL-based sessions (no more 'jsessionid' in the URL using 
            Tomcat) -->
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.myproject.system.ContextFinalizer</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

However, if I navigate to /test, I'm only getting a 404 error.

Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is working fine now. I removed the default servlet from my web.xml.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file in your web application called "/home/index.xhtml" (or something to that effect)? Please also post your web.xml if possible. Thanks!

Also, it seems that you have quite a few filters defined in your web.xml, but you do not define the rewrite filter. This *should* be fine, however, it is worth adding the filter manually and seeing what happens. The rewrite filter should be the first filter in your web.xml:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletRequestListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
   <listener-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.impl.RewriteServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
   <filter-name>OCPsoft Rewrite Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter</filter-class>
   <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>OCPsoft Rewrite Filter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Edited my post above, yes I do have a index.xhtml in my home directory

Comment: Edited my answer, try again?

Comment: Added the filter and listener above, no change. AFAIK, there is no additional filter needed for the newest version of rewrite while using servlet container 3.0.

Comment: That's right, I just wanted to make sure that the order was correct. Hmmm... do you think you could post on the support forums and attach a sample application that reproduces this problem (or upload and share a link to it somewhere else)? I should be able to help more with my hands on the app: http://ocpsoft.org/support/ (let me know if you have trouble creating an account.)